# .NET Webforms routing works on localhost but not on IIS 8

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, webforms, routes

I am creating a .NET web forms application and attempting to use friendly URLs for the first time. The application is targeting framework 4.7.1. Everything is easy and works great on localhost. When I deploy it to a testing server (which is running IIS version 8.5.9600.16384), I get some odd results. The page will route correctly, and retain the friendly url structure, if the routeUrl is equal to the physical page name, but if the routeUrl is not equal, it gives a 404. Even when the route does work, the route values don't come through to the page. Page.RouteData.Values.Count always comes back as 0, even when I'm setting a default value.

I have looked all over Stack Overflow and the rest of the internet and looked at I don't even know how many posts from people with similar problems, but in the few cases that there were suggested solutions, none of them worked for me. See below things I have changed in my web config based on those suggestions, all to no avail.

What I have right now:

RouteConfig.cs

```
    public static class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {

            routes.MapPageRoute( //"works", but no route values when navigate to /giftcard/something
                "new-giftcard",
                "giftcard/{action}",
                "~/giftcard.aspx",false, new RouteValueDictionary { { "action", "add" } });

            routes.MapPageRoute( //returns 404 when navigate to /random/something
                "randomtest",
                "random/{action}",
                "~/giftcard.aspx", false, new RouteValueDictionary { { "action", "test" } });

            var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
            settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
            routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
        }
    }
```

Global.asax

```
        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        }
```

Web.config (things I added based on research of possible issues, none of which helped)

```
 <system.webServer>
    <modules  runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"  >
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

All of this seems to work perfectly fine on localhost. Because it all works locally, there has to be something wrong with how IIS is handling the routing, but I am out of my area of expertise here, so any other ideas for what to change or how to debug would be great.

Here's my current settings on the live server again for reference:

IIS version 8

Application pool .NET 4.0 Integrated

Target framework .NET 4.7.1

I checked IIS Express on my local development machine, and it's version 10.

EDIT: further info - I tried it on a new test server with a fresh install of server 2012, and it seems to work. Unlike the test server described above, this new server has ONLY had .NET 4.0 installed. The first server is older and had .NET 3.5 and 4 both installed. Perhaps a conflict with versions of .NET?

Comment: Check which module is returning 404, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis then you can take actions.

Comment: did you enable the HTTP Redirection feature of iis?<system.webServer> <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"><remove name="UrlRoutingModule"/><add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /></modules><handlers><add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/></handlers> </system.webServer>

Comment: link:https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rjacobs/2010/06/30/system-web-routing-routetable-not-working-with-iis/

Comment: @JalpaPanchal I do remember seeing that link you posted at some point during my own research...I checked that HTTP redirection is enabled, and I added that stuff to my web config, and still nothing.

Comment: @LexLi a failed request tracing for the request for /random/something, which should match one of my routing rules, results in the following:

ModuleName
IIS Web Core 

Notification
MAP_REQUEST_HANDLER 

HttpStatus
404 

HttpReason
Not Found 

HttpSubStatus
0 

ErrorCode
The system cannot find the file specified.
 (0x80070002)

Comment: you could try some below steps like:1. Compare the applicationhost.config of working and nonworking server 2. Compare the Failed request tracing of working and nonworking server 3.Compare the Failed request tracing for a good URL and bad URL